# Margins for ggplot2 facet labels much too large when using high font size

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

When increasing font size to compensate for high dpi rendering in rmarkdown,  the labels for the facet wrap ggplot image have an unusually large margin.  In the example below, the vertical space above 'D', 'E', etc. is what I am trying to lower.  I have tried changed the `element_text` margin as well as the `panel.spacing` theme parameter. Setting those to zero does not change things much.

### Code

````
---
title: "PNG facet wrap test"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message =FALSE,fig.height=4)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.showtext=TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6.5, fig.height = 4, out.width = 6.5, out.height = 4)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="png", dev.args=list(type="cairo", pointsize=36), dpi=300)

require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
```

## Example image

```{r highdpi}
dia = ggplot2::diamonds %>% filter(cut=="Ideal", clarity=="SI2", color!="J")
ggplot(dia, aes(x=carat, y=price)) + facet_wrap(~color) + geom_point() + theme_light(36)
```
````

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: I don't think DPI has anything to do with your issue, I think the difference is `theme_light(36)` vs `theme_light(16)`. Your output is the way the graphs show up in the graphics window during an interactive session with those theme options.

Comment: The images are taken from a rendered word document and not an interactive session.

Comment: Yes, and you'll get similar images if you just run the plotting code in an interactive session which doesn't use the your chunk options and dpi. Hence the dpi is not the issue. The issue is that in the first one you use `theme_light(36)`, and in the second one you change it to `theme_light(16)`.

Comment: Fair enough, but my question is how do I increase the font size without having giant margins around the facet wrap labels?  I'll reword my question.

Comment: Does `theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(b = 0, t = 0) ) )` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! It seems like setting strip.text.x directly works while setting strip.text didn't.  Please add your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *ggplot2_2.2.1* you can use `strip.text.x` to change the margins of the strips with `margin`.  (In the development version you may be be able to do this [directly with `strip.text`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2248)).

Here I make the top and bottom margins 0:

```
ggplot(dia, aes(x=carat, y=price)) + 
     facet_wrap(~color) + 
     geom_point() + 
     theme_light(36) +
     theme(strip.text.x = element_text( margin = margin( b = 0, t = 0) ) )
```